# How to read values in page load in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an API called `dropdown-language` that returns something like:

```
{
  "res": [
    {
      "enabled": 0, 
      "flag": "gr"
    }, 
    {
      "enabled": 1, 
      "flag": "us"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I get the two elements on page load and store them in two global variables such as:

```
var one = { "enabled": 0 , "flag": "gr" }
var two = { "enabled": 1 , "flag": "us" }
```

So that I can use then in other parts of the same html page? This is what I have done so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
  url: "dropdown-language",
  success : function(data) {
    obj = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(obj);
  },
  async:false
});
</script>
```

Comment: Note that your JSON response is incorrect

Comment: you are right. fixed it.

Comment: If you -in your browser- actually replace the page name for `dropdown-language` does it show the json? So, if your website is: http://www.test.com/index.html and you change this for http://ww.test.com/dropdown-language does it show you the JSON?

Comment: sure. definitely. the API works fine.

Comment: what about helping me embed (hard-coded) the JSON as a string? this way - at least - I will be able to move on a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

I took liberty to update the script slightly, also, to add your response into another setup.

First the solution:

```
$.getJSON( "dropdown-language", function( data ) { // use getJSON for JSON: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/
    var response = data.res, // get 'res'
        flags = []; // prepare an array for flags

        /**
         * BETTER
         */
        response.forEach(function(element){ // loop through the response
            flags[element.flag] = element.enabled // add to the flags array, like flag['gr'] = 0
        });

        /**
         * KINDA WRONG
         * Will work, but you probably don't want this
         */
        var one = response[0],
            two = response[1];

    console.log(flags); // don't use alert, but display the object using console.log
}
```

The 'better' solution is because your result is now dynamic, what if tomorrow your JSON response has more flags?

Answer (score -2):

Declare two global variables before your ajax request and instantiate them in your success callback

```
var one, two;

$.ajax({
    url: "dropdown-language",
    success: function (data) {
        obj = JSON.parse(data);
        alert(obj);
        one = obj.res[0];
        two = obj.res[1];
    },
    async: false
});
```

It may be better to store `res` globally, if you can have more than two languages for example.

Comment: Or only two objects returned in res. I'm not sure the order matter though.

Comment: thanks but it doesn't seem to work - yet! I mean, I don't see the alert dialog. How to debug this?

Comment: Read the comment under your question, your JSON is not valid, remove the `,` after the `"flag":...` lines. To debug, hit F12, it will show the dev tools in any browser. You'll see the errors.

Comment: ok I fixed the typo, but still not able to see the alert dialog. what else could it be?

Comment: Does the console show errors? Are you sure your url is good? You could add an `error` handling function to your ajax params object to see what's happening: `$ajax({ url: ..., success: ..., error: ... })`.